GPT-4 Turbo hosted on Microsoft Azure Open AI. Operation does not work
I have Gpt-4-turbo model hosted on Microsoft Azure OpenAI service. I'm trying to access the model using Requests as well as openai and AzureOpenAI(from openai).
Only available option I came across is "chat.completion" and "completion". But not able to access that.
Error code: 400 - {'error': {'code': 'OperationNotSupported', 'message': 'The completion operation does not work with the specified model, gpt-4. Please choose different model and try again. You can learn more about which models can be used with each operation here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2197993.'}} 

I tried with chat completion and completion.
Also tried with requests.post, openai and openai.AzureOpenAI.
